# jslint type tool for css

Tags: css, validation, jslint

I am using JSLint to validate and inspect my javascript files. I find it very useful and helps me write better code. I have integrated it into Visual Studio through external tools.

I am looking for a similar tool but this time for CSS? Any other there to look at, mostly to carry out same tasks as JSLint.

Comment: duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644644/are-there-any-css-lint-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3C have an online [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input). <strike>It's not downloadable, but you may want to write a short script that sends the contents of you CSS files to W3C and returns the results.</strike>

It can be downloaded from [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html). (Thanks [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/david-dorward)... see comment below)

W3C also expose a [Web Service API for CSS validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html).

Comment: It's not downloadable? There is a download link ( http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html ) at the bottom of the homepage. It's a bit fiddly, but you do get a command line tool. I started wrapping a GUI around the classes at one point, so it is quite easy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

There's also http://csslint.net/.